# How do I detect Stripe payment pop up being closed within an Angular 2+ component's template?

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

So inside an Angular 4 controller I have this method called 'openCheckout' which is meant to make the Stripe payment pop-up to show. As you might be familiar from the Stripe documentation, inside the **handler.open** there is a an option 'closed' which triggers an anonymous function that is meant to do something, i.e. trigger a javscript function.

My question is: how do I get this to trigger a component method? i.e. one I called 'doSomethingWhenStripePopUpCloses()'.

I just need my component to know when the Stripe pop up has closed. Any suggestions in that direction also welcome.

```
openCheckout(productName: string, amount:number, tokenCallback) {
let stripe_amount_in_pennies = amount+'00';
let a = parseInt(stripe_amount_in_pennies);
amount = a;
let handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: tokenCallback
});

handler.open({
    name: 'test',
    description: productName,
    zipCode: false,
    currency: 'gbp',
    amount: amount,
    panelLabel: "Pay {{amount}}",
    allowRememberMe: false,
    email:this.user.email,
    closed: function() { doSomethingWhenStripePopUpCloses(); } 
});
}
```

Comment: did you *try* creating the `doSomethingWhenStripePopUpCloses()` method and invoking it like you have in your example?

Comment: As Mr. Frozen Peas mentioned: Have you tried creating the function you mentioned? Either way, the answer will be to put the function you want to call into a service, that either functions as an eventbus for the component you want to call, or you can look into using `observables` to inform the component of the state change. I would look at `subject`s and `behaviorSubject`.

Comment: I did try creating doSomethingWhenStripePopUpCloses(), but to invoke it, you have to be using it as this.doSomethingWhenStripePopUpCloses() . Problem is 'this.' is in a different scope. 
Mr.Pytth might be onto something...

Answer (score 1):

And here's the answer.

To trigger an Angular class method inside the Stripe's own code, instead of using:

```
function(){doSomethingWhenStripePopUpCloses();}
```

You should use the arrow function:

```
()=>{this.doSomethingWhenStripePopUpCloses();
```

In the code

```
handler.open({
name: 'test',
description: productName,
zipCode: false,
currency: 'gbp',
amount: amount,
panelLabel: "Pay {{amount}}",
allowRememberMe: false,
email:this.user.email,
closed: ()=>{this.doSomethingWhenStripePopUpCloses();} 
});
```